# I need help with an assignment

Tags: line-spacing

Why are they still different? THe positioning is messed up in some areas. The assignment was to make an identical document.

http://pdfcast.org/pdf/latex-3

http://pdfcast.org/pdf/latex-2

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a small [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. As it is, it's not a every informative question.

Comment: Your current question is too broad. It helps to ask specific questions like how to center the heading, how to change font, how to make list, ...

Comment: Please be more specific, and change the title to be more informative.

Comment: The question will be closed now. It could be reopened if the question was edited and improved to be better understandable.